Can I integrate WebRTC with AWS Chime meeting service?
I have an iOS use AWS Chime SDK, I want to improve group call service and presentation, share screen, casting resource on other machine,
Can I replicate it use the WebRTC integrate meeting Info from Chime Meeting API. Is it possible?
